# Create tabs in html/css so border disappears beneath active tab

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create tabs where there is a top border along the content, and then the active tab overlaps in such a way that there is no border between it and the content.

I've tried playing with negative margins, but it doesn't work. I'd like to do this without using position:absolute

http://jsfiddle.net/Py8BW/3/  (I'm using green and red, but they will be the same color in final result.)

```
<div class = "tab">inactive</div>
<div class = "tab tab_active">active</div>

<div class = "content"> 
</div>
```

.

```
.tab{
  width:70px  ;
     display:inline-block;
    background:green;
    height:50px;  
    // margin-bottom:-2px; /* makes both tabs look active */
}

.tab_active{
     margin-bottom:-2px; /* does nothing */
}

.content{
    border-top:2px solid black;
    width:200px ;
    background:red;
    height:200px;
}
```

Comment: like this http://jsfiddle.net/Py8BW/5/ ?

Comment: add `border-bottom:2px solid red;` on class `.tab_active`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another solution is just to add the `border-bottom` in the same color and `margin-bottom` on the class `.tab_active`.

```
.tab_active{
    margin-bottom: -2px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
```

```css
.tab {
  width: 70px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
  /* margin-bottom: -2px; makes both tabs look active */
}

.tab.active {
  margin-bottom: -2px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}

.content {
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">inactive</div>
<div class="tab active">active</div>
<div class="content"></div>
```

Comment: This worked well, thanks! Adding 2px to the height instead of adding a 2px border makes it look a little better if the tabs get left/right borders.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `z-index` and positioning. Give a higher `z-index` for the active tab, a slightly lower `z-index` for the content tab and an even lower `z-index` for inactive tab(s). This means that the inactive tabs will always be behind the content box which in turn will be behind the active tab.

Now give a `top: 2px` and `position: relative` to push the tab headers below a bit to overlap the content box. Now since content box is above the inactive tabs, the border of the content box will be visible above the tab header, but not for the active tab because that is above the content box.

```
.tab {
    width:70px;
    display:inline-block;
    background:red;
    height:50px;
    z-index:0; /* Pushes inactive tabs behind the content box */
    position: relative;
    top:2px;
}
.tab_active {
    z-index: 2; /* Pushed it before content box because of higher z-index */
}
.content {
    border-top:2px solid black;
    width:200px;
    background:red;
    height:200px;
    position: relative;
    z-index:1; /* Normal z-index */
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Py8BW/12/)

[**Updated Demo with borders**](http://jsfiddle.net/Py8BW/9/) - Just need to increase the `top` value.

**Update:** Alternately, set height of active tab to be equal to height of normal tab + height of border like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Py8BW/10/). Note that for this method to work the `margin-top` also should be changed according to the `border-width`.